# Electric charge of the Higgs mode in superconductivity

Tags: condensed-matter, potential, field-theory, higgs

I have a question about the Higgs mode in superconductivity. In this [doc](https://indico.ijclab.in2p3.fr/event/5201/contributions/17255/attachments/14335/17650/MAM-HiggsHunting-2019.pdf), it is said, page 12, that the Higgs mode has no electric charge. But it couples nonlinearly with the photon (in the phenomenological Ginzburg-Landau theory there is a term $\propto e^2 A^2 h$ with $A$ the vector potential and $h$ the Higgs field). I just don't understand how a field can be coupled to $A$ without having a charge. I hope to be clear.

Comment: Where do you see the nonlinear coupling between Higgs and A in these slides? Maybe I'm blind... As far as I am able to read, on page 10, they say "the SC amplitude ‘Higgs’ 
modes correspond to coherent oscillatory pairings and depairings of the Cooper pairs of electrons" So if one pair is created while another pair is destroyed, the mode corresponding to this has zero charge... Maybe you can find a review article on Higgs in condensed matter systems (maybe specifically SC's) that can help give details? Interesting topic...

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Thank you for your answer. Indeed the coupling term does not appear in this slide show. I read this [review][1], page 7 we can see the term of nonlinear interaction I mentioned in my first message. But this is only phenomenological and indeed I'm agree that when considering a microscopic theory (like BCS) the Higgs (amplitude mode) is only an oscillation of the gap and don't have any charge.

       [1] : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.09401.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it should be evident from your Abelian Higgs mechanism that your σ, or Higgs *h*, etc... mode is "dark"... a U(1) singlet, so it does not respond to gauge transformations, even before you coupled its larger doublet to photons via a charge. The thicket of symbols you have been thrown into obscures the basic symmetry structure that governs the mechanism.

Recall the *ungauged*, globally U(1) symmetric scalar doublet (I'm being cavalier with normalizations), of action
$$
\partial_\mu \phi^* \partial^\mu \phi -\lambda (\phi^* \phi - v^2/2)^2 .
$$
Its U(1) symmetry transformations act as $\delta \phi= i \epsilon\phi$, with $\epsilon$ the real, dimensionless infinitesimal parameter of the transformation. Thus,  the conserved Noether current is $J_\mu\propto i(\phi^*\partial_\mu \phi- \phi\partial_\mu \phi^*). $

Now, as you learned, SSBreaking is more transparent in the polar representation of the scalar field,
$$
\phi (x)  \equiv {h(x)+v \over \sqrt{2}} e^{i\theta(x)/v} ~~\leadsto \\
\delta h=0, ~~ \delta \theta =\epsilon v , ~~ J_\mu = -(v+h)^2\partial_\mu \theta /v, \\
{\cal L} =\frac{1}{2} \bigl( \partial_\mu h \partial ^\mu h +(1+h/v)^2 \partial_\mu \theta \partial ^\mu \theta\bigr ) -{\lambda \over 4} (h^2+2vh)^2 ,
$$
where the massless Goldstone field *θ* has dimensions of momentum ― like *φ*, *h*, and the order parameter *v*. The dross mode, *h*, has mass $\sqrt {2\lambda} ~ v$, as you can check, and is a singlet (invariant) under the U(1). Significantly, the potential does not depend on  *θ*!

Now, gauge this model with minimal coupling, $\partial_\mu \phi\mapsto (\partial_\mu -ieA_\mu)  \phi$, to obtain an irrelevant Maxwell term, the *same Higgs potential*, the *same* dark higgs kinetic terms; and, significantly, a few extra terms, in the goldston kinetic term,
$$
\frac{1}{2} (v+h)^2 (\partial_\mu \theta/v -e A_\mu  )  ^2.
$$

Through a gauge transformation, you may now *completely* absorb the goldston into the photon, to reduce this term to
$$
\frac{e^2}{2} (v+h)^2   A_\mu^2,
$$
which includes a mass term, *m=ev*, for the photon (inverse penetration length for the magnetic field); and a trilinear coupling $e^2v hA_\mu A^\mu$ over and above the evident quadrilinear coupling *γγhh*.

- Note there is no trace or remnant of *θ* in the system anymore: it has left the problem! Its degree of freedom is the *extra longitudinal polarization mode* of the massive *γ*,  that distinguishes it from its massless former self. Because of this mass, a magnetic field attenuates (dies off exponentially) as it enters the superconducting medium.

So, indeed, the higgs does couple to the photon with strength $e^2$, so it decouples for vanishing *e*.  Your reference by Shimano & Tsuji calls this "nonlinear coupling" to the extent it requires superstrong EM fields to express itself. It is of *O*($e^2$) in the amplitude, and *not* of *O(e)*, as expected in the conventional weak field EM couplings―see below.

But, in this topsy-turvy medium, where goldstons pop into and out of the medium,  the higgs is still characterized as "dark". It certainly does not couple to EM minimally, *O(e)*,  as you saw from its unaffected kinetic term, so you cannot slam a photon onto it and observe a deflection, because there is no such linear EM *γhh* coupling. That is what the admittedly imprecise rubric "dark" indicates.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. But I'm still confuse. So if I understand correctly, $h$ must be neutral because under the $U(1)$ transformation $\delta h = 0$. What I don't quiet get it's that we start with a charged $\phi$ field and after the SSB we end up with a $h$ field with no charge. Is it the Goldstone mode that takes the charge? 
I still have a problem talking about a gauge change when the photon "absorbs" the Goldstone mode.

Comment: Shouldn't we rather talk about a redefinition of the $A_\mu$ field which becomes $\partial _\mu \theta /v - e A_\mu$ ? (since by definition a gauge transformation does not modify the Lagrangian). And so in fact the Higgs interacts with a mixture of $A_\mu$ and the Goldstone (the famous massive photon). But everything is not completely clear yet, I have to think about it a bit more.

Comment: Indeed, the complex φ field is two fields: a neutral *h* and a charged Goldstone field θ permeating the non invariant vacuum (medium). The field redefinition of *A* is a gauge transformation preserving the Lagrangian.  But now the goldston has *disappeared* and turned into an extra polarization state of *A*. The *h* indeed interacts with *A*, through the "eaten" goldstone.

Comment: "The field redefinition of A is a gauge transformation preserving the Lagrangian." Indeed the new field $A_ \mu$ is again gauge invariant. But during a gauge transformation of the new $A_\mu$ one must also modify $\theta$ to keep the Lagrangian unchanged. Forgetting the transformation of $\theta$ gives the impression that the gauge symmetry $U(1)$ is broken. That's why I prefer to talk about redefinition instead of gauge transformation for $A_\mu$. 
Anyway, thanks again for your answer, it's much clearer now.